# Opening an audio file using app designer

Tags: matlab, audio

I'm trying to built a GUI with app designer. What I am trying to do is to open an audio file  using `uigetfile` and then use `audioread`. After it opens, I have the following error from `audioread`:

> The filename specified was not found in the MATLAB path.

```
function ButtonButtonPushed(app)           
[AttTrans,PathName] = uigetfile({'*.wav';'*.aif'},'Select audiofile');
[x,Fs]= audioread('AttTrans')
end
```

Is there something else I should do?

Comment: I vote to close this question, as general programming questions are more suitable for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Input variable `AttTrans` defined for the filename is used in a wrong way in `audioread()` function. Plus, you should add pathname as well, if you are importing an audio file from a path out of current folder.

Following change must work for you:

```
[FileName, PathName] = uigetfile({'*.wav; *.aif'}, 'Select audio file');
[x, Fs] = audioread([PathName FileName]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma is missing. Now it's working:

```
[FileName, PathName] = uigetfile({'*.wav; *.aif'}, 'Select audio file');
[x, Fs] = audioread([PathName , FileName]);
```